# Converting scaled and centered estimates to unstandardized estimates in R

Tags: r, standardized, glmmtmb

I am using the glmmTMB package in R to run a logistic regression glm model with fixed and random effects (random intercepts and slopes). For some background, I have 5 fixed covariates, one of which includes a quadratic (so really 6 fixed effects) and I am including random slopes for each of those 6 covariates. Prior to running my model, I have scaled and centered each covariate (using the `scale` function) and checked for correlation between covariates (other than the quadratic, correlation < 0.6). I would like to convert the estimates from the model (which are standardized) to unstandardized estimates because I need to create a predictive map in ArcGIS, which have unstandardized rasters. For obtaining unstandardized estimates for use in ArcGIS, I have tried running my model with the raw data (i.e. skipping the scale and center code) but I believe I am running into convergence issues because even though it runs without warnings, the estimates have large standard errors (10-100x larger than the estimate) and the relationship of the estimate (+ or -) flips between the standardized and unstandardized runs. I have found similar posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268031/unscale-and-uncenter-glmer-parameters), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642111/how-to-unscale-the-coefficients-from-an-lmer-model-fitted-with-a-scaled-respon/23643740#23643740), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324971/back-transform-coefficients-from-glmer-with-scaled-independent-variables-for-pre) but I don't think they are exactly my issue, or I am not understanding the math in the solutions. Advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to convert? Coefficients? Do you need to convert the random-effects components as well or just the fixed-effect components (i.e., population-level predictions rather than group-level predictions)? In a model *with interactions*, centering can definitely change the coefficients. Can you show us the results with/without centering & scaling? Have you tried any of the solutions in the other posts/can you be more specific about what doesn't apply?

Comment: can you provide some example data and code? And for predicting to raster cells it would probably be much easier to use terra::predict (and why not standardize the predictor rasters?).